# Correct Go/RabbitMQ way to "pop" one message off the queue?

Tags: go, kubernetes, rabbitmq, amqp

The first question I have is a design question really. This is my first time writing a service that uses a Queue and I am also new to Go. I am trying to determine whether I should write my worker in such a way that it simply pops one message off the queue, processes it, and the dies off. With things like Kubernetes this *seems* fairly trivial.

Or should I have a long-lived worker constantly waiting for new messages but that is relaunched if it dies (by a bug or accident)?

The reason I ask this question is that in order to implement the former it feels a little more "hacked up" because I have to write the following using the common go AMQP library from `streadway/amqp` (read the comments):

```
// Pop will extract a message from the AMQP queue
func (v *Queue) Pop() (data []byte, err error) {
    msgs, err := v.Channel.Consume(
        v.QueueName, // queue
        v.ConsmerID, // consumer
        true,        // auto-ack
        false,       // exclusive
        false,       // no-local
        false,       // no-wait
        nil,         // args
    )
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // We have to use for .. range because Consume returns
    // "<-chan Delivery" but if we only want ONE message popped off
    // we return on the first one
    for data := range msgs {
        return data.Body, nil
    }

    // We should never get this far...
    return nil, errors.New("Something went wrong")
}
```

Furthermore what is `<-chan Delivery` in this case? It seems like some sort of "stream" or object that you can plug into. Is there a way to not have to write a for-loop for these data types?

EDIT: I have also discovered that it appears that this code will dequeue the ENTIRE queue even though it only does a for-loop iteration once (as show in the code above). I am not sure why this happens either?

Relevant links to code:

- https://github.com/streadway/amqp/blob/master/channel.go#L1049
- https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/blob/master/go/worker.go
- https://github.com/fatih/amqp-examples/blob/master/consumer.go#L132

Comment: In Kubernetes land a long-lived process is definitely better: the startup time for a pod can be non-trivial, and if the process exits too quickly too often, you'll wind up in the dreaded `CrashLoopBackOff` state and it can be minutes before you get scheduled again.

Comment: Channel operators are covered in the Tour: https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2 and following.

Comment: This guy on GitHub is more-or-less doing the same thing but processes a batch of messages. However I am just out of my depth with what is going on with Channels and Go Routines. Would either of you care to do a quick TL;DR for what is going on here within the context of this question and design? https://github.com/fatih/amqp-examples/blob/master/consumer.go#L132

Answer (score 5):

To simply take a single object from a `<-chan Delivery`, don't use a `range` loop, but the [channel operator `<-`](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2):

```
data := <- msgs
return data.Body, nil
```

As to why your entire queue is emptied as soon as you fetch one message: This is most likely due to the [Consumer prefetch](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html). When consuming messages, the client will actually not pop them from the broker one-by-one, but in batches of configurable size (if I recall correctly, around the order of 32 or 64 messages by default). As soon as the broker has published this batch of messages to your consumer, they'll be in your `msgs` channel; and if you don't read from that channel any more after getting the first message, the rest of them will be gone (at least, with `auto-ack` enabled -- otherwise, they'll be requeued after the channel is closed).

To only fetch one message at a time, use the channel's [`QoS` function](https://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp#Channel.Qos) (with the first parameter being the prefetch count):

```
err := v.Channel.Qos(1, 0, false)
```